# How to add a label for a table? I get the "missing $ sign inserted" error even though everythings alright

Tags: tables, errors, labels, ref

This is a sample code of the table which I can't label:

```
    \documentclass[a4paper, 
        pointlessnumbers, 
        %draft,
        parskip=half,
        automark
            ]{scrartcl}
    
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt} 
    
    \usepackage[a4paper, left=2.2cm, right=2.2cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm,]{geometry}
    \usepackage{scrpage2}
    \clearscrheadfoot
    \pagestyle{scrheadings}
    
    \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
    
    
    \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx,color}
    
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    
    \usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm, amsfonts} 
    \usepackage{latexsym}
    \usepackage[decimalsymbol=comma]{siunitx} 
    
    
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage{tabulary}
    \usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} 
    \usepackage[centerlast,small,sc]{caption}
    \usepackage{here}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    
    \usepackage{titling}
    
    \usepackage{subfigure}
    
    
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    
    
        \renewcommand{\i}{\mathrm{i}}
        \newcommand{\e}{\mathrm{e}}
        \newcommand{\diff}{\mathrm{d}}
        \newcommand{\figref}[1]{Abb. \ref{#1}} 
    
        \newcommand{\ImNew}{\operatorname{Im}}
        \newcommand{\ReNew}{\operatorname{Re}}
        
        \newcommand{\xdot}{\! \, \cdot \! \,}
        \newcommand{\funof}[1]{{\color{gray}(#1)}}
        
    %Titelseite
    \title{Blockpraktikum 1 \\ SC Optische Aktivität und Saccharimetrie}
    \author{...}
    \date{Versuchsdurchführung}
    
    %Dokument
    \begin{document}
    \setcounter{page}{0}
    \maketitle
    \thispagestyle{empty} % Keine Seitenzahl auf Titelseite
    \ofoot{\upshape\thepage}
    
    \clearpage
    %Inhaltsverzeichnis
    %\thispagestyle{empty}
    \tableofcontents
    
    \clearpage
    %Hauptdokument
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \ihead{\upshape\scriptsize \leftmark}
    \ohead{\upshape\scriptsize \thetitle}
    %\ifoot{\upshape \scriptsize}
    \ofoot{\upshape\thepage}
    
Durch die Drehrichtung lässt sich feststellen ob es sich um Glucose oder Fructose handelt
In der Tabelle $\ref{Drehwinkel und Konzentrationsbestimmung dreier unbekannter Proben}$ und Konzentrationsbestimmung dreier unbekannter Proben wurde mit S. die Zuckersorte und mit F. und G. jeweils Fructose beziehungsweise Glucose bezeichnet.
\begin{table} [h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline 
    Probe & S. &$\alpha (1.)$ in $^\circ$ & $\alpha (2.)$ in $[^\circ]$ & $\alpha (3.)$ in $[^\circ]$ & $\overline{\alpha}$ in $[^\circ]$ & c \\ 
    \hline 
    X1 & F. & 0,1 & -3,2 &-2,8 & $-2,0 \pm 2,1_{zuf} \pm 0,05_{sys}$ & $0,0110  \pm 0,01_{zuf} \pm 0,0032_{sys}$ \\ 
    \hline 
    X2 & F. & -4,8 & -5,9 & -5,8 & $-5,5 \pm 0.7_{zuf} \pm 0,05_{sys}$ & $0,0309 \pm 0,004_{zuf} \pm 0,0032_{sys}$ \\ 
    \hline 
    X3 & G. & 9,6 & 9,4 & 10,5  & $9,8 \pm 0,7_{zuf} \pm 0,05_{sys}$ & $0,0943  \pm 0,007_{zuf} \pm 0,0032_{sys}$ \\ 
    \hline 
    \end{tabular} 
    \label{Drehwinkel und Konzentrationsbestimmung dreier unbekannter Proben}
    \caption{Drehwinkel und Konzentrationsbestimmung dreier unbekannter Proben}
\end{table}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: how old is your tex system? Unrelated: but \label should go after the \caption, and it should be a key not a full text.

Comment: I tried to put label after caption, but unfortunately the same error is getting displayed. I don't know how old it is I don't know anything about latex

Comment: Look in your log-file, it will tell you how old your system is. And if it old then better don't use spaces or curious chars in a label.

Comment: Its the pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018)

Comment: Do you know if I could use any other command to add a label for the table?

Comment: what do you mean by label here? `\label` is just an internal identifier for cross references, it is not printed. `\caption` makes the visible text.  Note also beware using `\renewcommand` on core latex commands `\renewcommand{\i}{\mathrm{i}}` will break any use of accented i , also what is the intention of `\! \, \cdot \! \,` ? the negative and positive spaces exactly  cancel each other out so this is just the same as `\cdot`

Comment: Simply use `\label{tab:Drehwinkel}`, then you can use `\ref{tab:Drehwinkel}`